# SAP Commerce Cloud multisite SOLR configuration

Tags: java, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Kindly help with the multi-site solr configuration.
We have a multi-brand shop, deployed to Commerce Cloud.
Currently we have a pretty simple search by material number which returns all the products according to it.
We have common product catalog for all products and would like to limit solr search result by returning only the products for the current Base Site.
Products have a parameter of Complex type which can be used to distinguish a site. Each product might have more then one site.
Doing it on the DAO level is pretty easy, but currently we use OOB search and not overriding product search.

Could you suggest please, is it possible to configure SOLR in this way?

Of course we can filter results afterwards, but hybris is powerful enough to cope with it, I believe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.